# Unexpected/Wrong typescript compiler checks for null inside array functions

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript function that looks similar to this:

```
const myFunction = () => {
    if(!props.object) return;
    if (someCondition) {
      return randomArray.items.find(item => item.id === props.object.someID)
    }
   ...
  }
```

props.object is of type `FooObject | null` and even after checking, the compiler still throws this error as if `props.object` could still possibly be null.

What I have also discovered is that this only happens inside the functions created by arrays.
So if I were to write the following:

```
const myFunction = () => {
    if(!props.object) return;
    const foo = props.object.property1;
   ...
  }
```

then props.object doesn't trigger the `null` error  and `foo` has the type of `property1` (as expected).

I've researched this and didn't find any solution except for using the `!` operator, which just bypasses the checks and is not a desired behavior. I could also check everytime I use `props.object` to verify for `null` with the `&&` or the ternary operator, but seems redundant, as one check, at the start of the function should be all that is needed. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that others can paste into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Pseudocode isn't really sufficient.  Also, you're not using the TypeScript Compiler API at all, so the tag is inappropriate (using the compiler is just "typescript"; using the compiler **API** is something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed unconvenient, however the guard can't be automatically applied to the expression used in the callback body.

Consider this code (it's almost yours)

```
type Foo = {
  someID: string
}

type Props = {
  object: Foo | null;
}

function myFunction( props: Props, randomArray: string[] ) {
  if ( !props.object ) return;

  return randomArray.find(item => item === props.object.someID ); // compile error
}
```

Suppose this works and doesn't produce any errors.

And now consider something as compilicated as:

```
...
function myFunction( props: Props, randomArray: string[] ) {
  if ( !props.object ) return;

  setTimeout( () => { props.object = null }, 500 );

  setTimeout( () => randomArray.find(item => item === props.object.someID ), 1000 );

  ...

}
```

This code first clears `props.object` and only then executes the callback. This would throw an exception in runtime but the compiler would still allow it.

So, another possible workaround is to bind the offensive expression to a local variable:

```
function myFunction( props: Props, randomArray: string[] ) {
  if ( !props.object ) return;

  let propsObject = props.object;

  return randomArray.find(item => item === propsObject.someID ); // no error
}
```

(other workarounds that involve `!` and checking inside the callback were already mentioned in your question)

Comment: You're right, this solves the problem, but I can't seem to grasp why the expression used in the callback would throw such error, as the code is synchronous in this case and should be guaranteed that the entire function block is executed line by line when executed